# R: Skip a vignette being run on CRAN R CMD check

Tags: r, package, cran, vignette

I have a number of vignettes in an `R` package that are slow to run. As I understand it, a CRAN `R CMD check` will not rebuild the vignette but will run its corresponding code.

Since the vignettes are slow to run, I don't think the adhere to the CRAN policy. But the vignettes are useful examples that have figures. So I was wondering if it's possible to skip running vignette code only for a CRAN `R CMD check`, a bit like you can skip a unit test using `testthat::skip_on_cran()`?

Comment: Look at `R CMD check --help`.

Comment: Aah okay thanks, I also wondered if there's a way to specify that CRAN uses this option?

Comment: You can also run (parts of) the vignettes and install them as pre-built documentation so that they don't run each time. That introduces a threat they stop working correctly and the need for you to rebuild them each time you update the package code, but can get you around this timing issue.

Comment: @Jack Did you find a solution to skip running vignette code on CRAN?

Comment: I had a work around but you prompted me to get to the bottom of this. I'll write up as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Dirk's comment about `R CMD check` is `--help`ful. You will see a `--no-vignettes` flag.

If you're using `devtools` from the R console, just use:

`devtools::check(vignettes = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I just found there is an environment variable used by `devtools` called `NOT_CRAN`, and we should be able to use the same ideas to check if things are being run as CRAN. I believe wrapping code in the following `if` statement will mean it is only run if you are not using the `--as-cran` statement.

```
if (identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN", unset = "true"), "true")) {
    ###CODE HERE###
}
```

I think even if this has been set by `devtools` it should still work.

Sources: [Testing -- R Packages by Hadley Wickham](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html); `testthat` package source; `devtools` package source.

Comment: The code runs both when I build the vignette and when I call `devtools::check()`, where  `cran = TRUE` is the default and checks using the same settings as CRAN. I'll see if it works when I release on CRAN.